# Php how to add backslash inside array of strings

Tags: php, json, backslash

I have a below array:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => CLICK
        [1] => CSC
    )
```

After json_encode I got below one.

```
"["CLICK","CSC"]"
```

How to convert this into `"[\"CLICK\",\"CSC\"]"` this.

Any one help.

Comment: The quotes at the beginning and end aren't really in the string, they're just how you write a string literal in the program.

Comment: why would you add JSON escape without any need?

Comment: There is no need to escape this JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some info was missing which I got after discussion.

They are manually replacing a lot of characters before returning json. Out of them they also include `[ => "[` and `] => ]"` due to their backend implications.

A simple `json_encode` was solution for this along with skipping those character replacement for specific this key.

Answer (score 0):

Source:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    "CLICK", "CSC"
];
echo json_encode(json_encode($arr)) . "\n";
```

Result:

```
"[\"CLICK\",\"CSC\"]"
```

Comment: But I dont need ""[\"zhang\",\"wang\"]"" that double quotes ...needed one "[\"CLICK\",\"CSC\"]"

Comment: ur answer have two double quotes at front and back...can u remove that one double quotes from both front and back. Then ur answer is what i expect

Comment: how to return that one

Comment: when print shows correctly.how to return.when return i got "\""[\\\"CLICK\\\",\\\"CSC\\\"]"\"\n"

Comment: still i got like this only "\""[\\\"CLICK\\\",\\\"CSC\\\"]"\""